# Python subprocess error caused by integer argument

Tags: python, subprocess

I used `subprocess` to run a program.

However, I passed an integer `0` and it returned an error as shown below.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

```
threading.Thread(target = subprocess.check_output, args = [["python", program, data1_path, data2_path, 0]]).start()

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: Try quoting it? `"0"`

Comment: The positional arguments are input to `program`; the problem appears to be that `program` expects an iterable item (sequence) at that position, but you've supplied a scalar.  Please supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the guidelines.

Comment: @Matt. It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the program, I need to use `int()` to convert the string `'0'`  to integer.